# How to install a "Game for Windows" game on Steam?

Tags: games-for-windows-live, call-of-duty-world-at-war

I have *Call of Duty: World at War* for PC, and it says it is a "Game for Windows". How do I get it downloaded on Steam without having to put the game's disk in the optical drive? Or how do I get the Games for Windows application?

Comment: You currently have a disk, but you are unable to put the disk in the computer? Does the game include a key to be redeemed on Steam? Or for Games for Windows (Live)? If it only includes a Games for Windows (Live) key, it likely doesn't even use Steam.

Comment: Could possibly extract it to an external hard drive on another computer

Comment: Hasn't GfWLive been shut down?

Comment: @Shadur No. And there's a difference between "Games for Windows Live", which is a service, and the "Games for Windows" banner some companies put on their case art -- which simply means it's a game designed for Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: @TZHX - The game in question based on the author's statement is a "Game for Windows Live' game.

Comment: @Ramhound err... No, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the CD key, try to redeem it on Steam!

[How do I register a CD Key to activate a product on Steam?](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352)

Comment: `Call of Duty: World at War` Retail CD keys are not accepted on Steam.

Answer (score 2):

Only some games, [listed here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601), have the option to redeem a retail purchase onto your Steam account.

Call of Duty: World at War is **not** one of these. You will need to install it using the CD, and enter the CD Key where appropriate in the installation process.