# How do I install a game to Games for Windows?

Tags: games-for-windows-live, call-of-duty-world-at-war

So I have Call of Duty World at War, and it's for Games for Windows it says on the cover. I downloaded Games for Windows, but how do I download the game through it? Whenever I try to it just has it's own thing.

Comment: Why are you asking how to install the same game [two different ways](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165249/how-to-install-a-windows-game-for-steam)?

Comment: Because idk lol just want to know how plz

Comment: Unless you have an actual problem to solve, these types of questions don't work very well at all.  I would suggest picking one of them, and updating it with what you've tried to do to install it.  If you run into a problem, that's when you ask us.  We don't do so well with questions that don't actually have a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a Windows game for steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165249/how-to-install-a-windows-game-for-steam)

Comment: @Stevoisiak That question is equally unfocused, though.

Answer (score 4):

**Games for Windows** is simply something that gets put on the box art for some games, to suggest that they should work well with Windows Vista or Windows 7. It is separate from the **Games for Windows Live** (or **GFWL**) service which can be used to integrate the game with Xbox-style achievements, online multiplayer, and some DRM capabilities.

The retail copies of Call of Duty: World at War is **not** a GFWL game. You will need to install it with using the CD, and enter the CD Key when appropriate in the installation process.

The application you installed was probably the GFWL Store, which is used for buying DLC for various GFWL games (for example, Microsoft Flight). However, this does not have an option to download GFWL games that you've previously linked to your account through a CD key -- you still need to install them in the way you originally did. And in any case, *this is not relevant for this game*.

**TL;DR**: Use the CD to install your game.